# Заменить слова с заглавными буквами

Tags: php

Встречаются в тексте слова, которые пишутся КАПСОМ целыми предложениями. Подскажите, как такие слова грамотно находить и приводить в нижний регистр ?

Главное, учитывать что есть аббревиатуры, т.е , по-сути, искать слова длиной от 4-6 символов

Comment: Регулярные выражения.

Comment: спасибо, ваш ответ сделал мой день

Comment: @SarkisAllahverdian Какой вопрос - такой ответ (тем более что это не ответ, а комментарий). Учтите, что аббревиатуры тоже бывают длинные  - [ГНИИХТЭОС](http://www.eos.su/) например. А в предложении, набранном капсом, будут слова 4-6 символов длиной.

Comment: Для таких целей нужно учитывать многое, также нужен словарь слов, аббревиатур, имен, и прочее. В последующем лучше все это обрабатывать на этапе записи в базу.

Answer (score 3):

С помощью регулярных выражений:

```
$str = 'КАПСОМ МВД';

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '~\b[A-ZА-ЯЁ]{4,6}\b~u',
    function($m){
        return mb_strtolower($m[0]);
    },
    $str
);
```

Результат:

```
капсом МВД
```